# Solaris 10 - Updating Python & Adding Libraries

Tags: python, solaris-10

I am very new to the `Unix` world and would like some information for a project.
Currently our servers run `Python 2.6.4` which I believe comes with `Solaris 10`.
I would like to know how one would update `Python` from `2.6` to `3.7+`.
More specifically, does `Solaris`/Oracle offer any packages or tools to aide in this?

Secondly my project uses two libraries not included in with python. Those libraries are `Plot.ly` (plotly) and `Pandas`. How would one make these libraries available on the desired server? Are there any packages for libraries like these?

(*note I have MyOracleSupport access*)

I am mostly looking for documentation on how to accomplish my goal with as little effort/time possible (following standards). I am working very closely with my sysadmin on this but because it is my project, I need to make sure moving it a live environment as simple as possible.

**I will add edits to supply additional information if needed, as well as followup**

**EDIT 1:** I have some servers running `Solaris 11` with `Python 2.7` which would prevent needing the upgrade on that system **but** would still need `libs`. That being said the `Python` team plans to stop supporting `2.X` after Jan 1, 2020.

Comment: Solaris 10 is nearly 15 years old. A lot of modern stuff simply won't run on it, or has never been backported. Your first step should be to look at the specific packages to see if they support Solaris 10, and perhaps contact their developers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , if Im not able to find any solaris specific packages on something like openCSW, does that mean `plotly` and `pandas` might not be supported? I can find `pip` which was used to install those to my local machine but that is all.

Comment: It looks like both of those are documented to require Python 2.7 (or 3.x). There may be other requirements that I didn't see from a quick look. Again your best bet is to have a chat with their developers regarding system requirements/Solaris 10 compatibility.